# Split every record in a Pyspark Dataframe and write them as Individual text files

Tags: xml, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data frame that can have upto 400k records every day.  It has just 2 columns. One is a kind of primary-key and the other one is a very lengthy xml record.
My requirement is to created hdfs folders named after the Primary-key and then stored the xml record as a text file.

Sample HDFS Structure below

```
../primary-key1/<xml-data1>
../primary-key2/<xml-data2>
...
...
../primary-key400k/<xml-data400k>
```

Im currently extracting the primary key column into a List and then looping the list and then filter the dataframe based on primary key and writing the record. This will take days to complete processing. My Sample code below

```
df1 = spark.table(db.tablename)
df1.count()
394000
>>> df1.printSchema()
root
 |-- primary_key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- xml_data: string (nullable = true)

df2 = df1.sort(col("primary_key")).cache()
#Extract the Primary_key column as Sorted List
primary_key_list= df2.rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()

hdfs_path ="mypath/xml_data_staging/" 

for i in range(0 , len(primary_key_list)):
  pkey = str(primary_key_list[i])
  print("Processing-Row" + pkey + ":" + str(i)) 
  df3 = df2.filter(df2.primary_key == pkey).select(df2.primary_key,df2.xml_data)
  df3.write.partitionBy('primary_key').format("text").save(hdfs_path+primary_key)
```

Above code is taking ages (approx 1 day) to process 394000 records.  Please advise a better way

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is to created hdfs folders named after the Primary-key
> and then stored the xml record as a text file.

If your requirement is to have a sub-folder per primary key value, then standard partitioning should be enough and your code could be simplified to:

```
df1 = spark.table(db.tablename)
hdfs_path ="mypath/xml_data_staging/" 

df1.write.partitionBy('primary_key').format("text").save(hdfs_path)
```

So loop `for .. range()` seems redundant in this case. Also, it will be way faster, since instead of 400k jobs pyspark will have just one to execute